# SQL: How to get rows from same table column in two different orders with limit to get max 3 values and min 3 values

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, union, limit

```
SELECT t1.HighestFunds, t2.lowestFunds
from
   (select FundAmount as HighestFunds 
    from Convergence_Dataset
    order by FundAmount
    DESC LIMIT 3) t1,
   (select FundAmount as lowestFunds
    from Convergence_Dataset
    order by FundAmount ASC
    LIMIT 3 ) t2;
```

Expecting 3 HighestFunds and 3 lowestFunds  from Convergence_Dataset.FundAmount,
Instead of getting 3 rows of column(HighestFunds , lowestFunds), I am getting 9 rows.
FYI, I am working on apache spark sql. (Databricks)

Comment: What database engine are you working with?

Comment: 3 * 3 = 9. (You're doing a cross join.)

Comment: @2189490, I am using SQL in spark pool, it is throwing the result the same as a cross join.

Comment: @jarlh, I am not using cross join, but it is responding in that way.

Comment: Indeed you are doing a cross join, an implicit one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a union query here:

```sql
(SELECT FundAmount FROM Convergence_Dataset ORDER BY FundAmount DESC LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT FundAmount FROM Convergence_Dataset ORDER BY FundAmount LIMIT 3)
ORDER BY FundAmount;
```

Note that in the event that your table has less than 6 records, then the same fund amount could be reported as both a highest and lowest amount.

We could also achieve this using `ROW_NUMBER` (or `RANK`):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT FundAmount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FundAmount) rn1,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FundAmount DESC) rn2
    FROM Convergence_Dataset
)

SELECT FundAmount
FROM cte
WHERE rn1 <= 3 OR rn2 <= 3
ORDER BY FundAmount;
```